# Rails returning UTC instead of just text with Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm working with Rails (4.2.6) and PostgreSQL, I have a table which contains a field named `end_time` of type Time, the problem I have is the next:

```
SELECT end_time FROM group_periods;
```

Will result in:

```
| end_time |
| 08:00:00 |
```

As you can see it only brings the text that is contained in the field (`08:00:00`) but if I try to do It in Rails it will bring in `end_time` a Time Object even if I cast it to text

```
GroupPeriod.select("end_time")
```

Will result in:

```
   => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<GroupPeriod id:nil, end_time: "2000-01-01 08:00:00">]>
```

after I try to access to `end_time` object it brings a Time object for Ruby.

I also have tried, resulting in the same:

```
GroupPeriod.select("end_time::text")
GroupPeriod.select("to_char(end_time, 'HH24:MI') end_time")
```

How could I get the field `end_time` as a string so whenever I access the field I get the same result as Postgres?

## EDIT

There is no chance to do a strftime and get te string format on every record due to I have thousands of records, that's the main reason I have already tried to cast the field as a text so rails would return a string instead of a Time object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the attribute accessor for `end_time` on the model and return the attribute before type casting

Something like

```
class GroupPeriod < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def end_time
    self.end_time_before_type_cast
  end

  ...
end
```

Documentation

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/BeforeTypeCast.html

Comment: Hey man, If I try to access to it as if the model was a Hash, it isn't triggering  that method, any option?

Comment: Umm. You could try `group_period[:end_time_before_type_cast]` or `group_period.attributes_before_type_cast[:end_time]` or `group_period.read_attribute_before_type_cast('end_time')`

Answer (score 0):

Rail's `ActiveRecord` casts the attribute values to Ruby objects. So, when you query using ActiveRecord's API on the model, it will return you the model object with the values as corresponding Ruby objects.

If you want to get the time string from the object's `time` attribute, you could use `strftime` method on time.

```
GroupPeriod.select("end_time").first.end_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Documentation:

- [Time#strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime)

Comment: The problem I have is that is not only a record, are thousands, and besides that I have also trying to cast the field as text so rails would return it as a string instead and I'm having not success

Answer (score 0):

You can set the global default time format:

In an initializer:

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = '%H:%M:%S'
```

or in your `config/locales/en.yml`:

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      default: '%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: This would change the format for the whole application, ain't it?